# Starting executable on a different computer

Tags: c++, windows, opencv

I made a program using Visual Studio 2012 with compiler VC11, platform toolset v110 running on a net framework v4.0 on Win7. In addition to Windows libraries, I used a third-party library, OpenCV, whose path I linked directly to my project.

Include directories: "E:\opencv\build\include"

Linker directories: "E:\opencv\build\x86\vc11\staticlib*.lib"

Now I'm trying to start that executable on a different PC and program immediately crashes with typical Win7 message that the program has stopped unexpectedly. I don't know which net framework that PC uses. Versions of OpenCV are identical on my PC and the other PC. My PC and the other PC both use Windows 7 OS. I built the program in Release mode.

I don't exactly know how do programs work after compiling, but I think that the problem is that the path to the OpenCV library on the other PC is different than the path on my PC. Since OpenCV dlls are located in the library directory, program can't fetch them (since it has a different path to the OpenCV library) and thus results with error. I think that linking a relative path to the OpenCV library would solve the problem.

I'd like to know whether this would make the program work. If other PC uses different net framework than my PC, will it result in error?

I can't solve the problem using trial and error since I used my desktop PC to make the program and I need to demonstrate it on a desktop PC  which has VS2013 installed with VC12 framework and compiling a modified solution results with version mismatch error.

Comment: Update your questions with details about the *other* PC, such as operating system version.  Also, did you copy *all* the necessary DLLs?  Did you build in release mode?

Comment: reduce your program (e.g. start a new hello world program) without opencv etc and try whether that would work. be 100% sure that it is not a problem in your program logic (e.g. accessing a path/device that doesnt exist on the other pc)

Comment: Mine and other PC both use Win7. All dlls are in library folder, but path to the library is different on my PC. Executable was built in release mode.

Comment: @Micka - only external data used in a program is one video file and it was correctly stored on the other PC. Even if video doesn't exist or isn't accessed properly, program should printout error and close properly.

Comment: opencv libs shouldnt be the problem at all since you used static linking, so the opencv stuff was completely added to your program. did you compile opencv yourself? (e.g. optimized for that platform)

Comment: I think PE Explorer can show you missing dlls

Comment: I downloaded opencv exe and installed it. I haven't compiled it (at least I think so :D ), I just added paths to include and .lib files. One other thing is that there are different .lib files for vc11 and vc12 compiler (I added only libs for vc11), don't know if it makes a difference.